# cakephp dropdown box and arrays

Tags: arrays, cakephp, find

Hi all I have a dropdown box on a view. I have a find statement that returns a list of templates,  when I debug the find, it prints out the correct list of template.id and template.name however when I submit the form it carries across the number it is in the list for example if I select the 5th template in a list it saves the template_id = 5 NOT the actual template id number.

```
//Retrieve Account Id of current User       
$accountid=$this->Auth->user('account_id');

//conditions for template arrays
$conditions=
array('AND' => array(
    array('Template.account_id' => $accountid),
    array('Template.active' => 1)
));

//An array of all Templates belonging to the current User's Account
$templates=$this->Template->find('list', array(
    'conditions' => $conditions));
```

when I debug $templates I get this print out

```
array(
    (int) 1 => 'Consulting- Bus',
    (int) 2 => 'Consulting- Pers',
    (int) 7 => 'ClientEdge',
    (int) 8 => '11111',
    (int) 9 => 'testSUn',
    (int) 10 => 'Test Bruce Review',
    (int) 11 => 'Test Bruce 3 = Final'
```

when I select for example 'Test Bruce Review' and hit submit and debug the value it prints out '6', the 6th item in the dropdown box when I want it printing out 10 when I debug it.

here is the snippet from the form relating to this dropdown box

```
<tr><td><?php echo "Template: "?></td>
<td><?php echo $this->Form->input('template_id', array('label'=>false,'type'=>'select','options'=>$templates));?></td></tr>
```

how can I remedy this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an issue with merging my arrays that caused the death of my template.id